# Unable to show icon in Pdf view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I hope you all are fine. The problem is that I am trying to show icons in pdf but it is not showing. Here is the error that I am getting

**Unable to find a font to draw "" (U+e0cd) try to provide a TextStyle.fontFallback**

I have tried many ways but couldn't find any solution. If someone finds any solution, please do share that with me. I am looking forward to your answers. Thanks!

**Here Is the Code:**

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart ';
    import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
final pdfDocument = pw.Document();

    pdfDocument.addPage(pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(20),
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Column(children: [
          pw.Container(
              padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: pw.Column(
                children: [
                  pw.Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: pw.Row(children: [
                      pw.Container(
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: pw.BorderRadius.circular(75),
                          color: PdfColors.amber,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                                image: FileImage(
                                  File(
                                    resumeController.selectedImagepath.value,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill) */
                        ),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      pw.Expanded(
                        child: pw.Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            resumeText('Usama Ali', 25),
                            pw.SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            pw.Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  pw.Icon(
                                    const pw.IconData(0xe0cd),
                                    color: PdfColor.fromHex("#12727f"),
                                  ),
                                  pw.SizedBox(
                                    width: 5,
                                  ),
                                  resumeText('0310-4241301', 13),
                                ]),
                            pw.SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            pw.Row(
                              children: [
                                pw.Icon(
                                  const pw.IconData(0xe318),
                                  color: PdfColor.fromHex("#12727f"),
                                ),
                                pw.SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                pw.Expanded(
                                  child: resumeText(
                                      'usamaali185.ua@gmail.com', 13),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            pw.SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            
                            pw.Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                            pw.Icon(
                                  const pw.IconData(58136),
                                  color: PdfColor.fromHex("#12727f"),
                                ),
                                pw.SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                pw.Expanded(
                                  child: resumeText('Lahore', 13),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: const pw.BoxDecoration(
                  color: PdfColors
                      .grey300 /* , boxShadow: [
                pw.BoxShadow(
                  color: PdfColors.black,
                  offset: PdfPoint(0, 0.5),
                )
              ] */
                  )),
        ]);
      },
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use pageTheme** with materialIcons

Steps

1- download materialIcons from [this_link](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v98/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNZ.ttf) and paste in assets, dont forget to update pubspec.yaml  and pub get.

2- Make a function that returns pageTheme like

```
Future<pw.PageTheme> pageTheme(PdfPageFormat format) async {

final materialIcons = await rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/materialIcons.ttf");

  final materialIconsTtf = pw.Font.ttf(materialIcons);
  return pw.PageTheme(
    pageFormat: format,
    theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
      icons: materialIconsTtf,
    ),
  );
}
```

3- Get pageTheme where async possible

```
  final pageTheme = await myPageTheme(format);
```

4- Asign pageTheme to pw.Page like

```
pdfDocument.addPage(pw.Page( pageTheme: pageTheme));
```